# HowTo animate filtering of items displayed in an ItemsControl (WPF)

Tags: wpf, animation, datatemplate, itemscontrol, datatrigger

I'm currently creating a control that is mainly just an `ItemsControl` displaying some items.
In addition I have some controls which allows the user to filter the items in that `ItemsControl`.

What I'm trying to do is to make it better visible to the user which items are removed when the filter is applied.

So what I did was instead of really filtering the `ICollectionView`, I introduced a new property `IsVisible` on the VM used for each item.
Then I added a `ScaleTransform` as `LayoutTransform` to the `DataTemplate`, and I added a `DataTrigger` to animate the transform:

```
<Style x:Key="FilterCollapse" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY"
                                         To="0"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:0.0"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY"
                                         To="1"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource FilterCollapse}">
        <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
```

If the User now filters everything works fine.
But the problem I have is if the anything changed in the list (adding new items, ...) the `Storyboard` is applied again, although the user did filter anything.

The reason for it is, that after the list has been changed, the `DataTemplate` will be recreated, with a ScaleY of "1", then the `DataTrigger` is applied again, and the scoreboard applied again.

In this case I would like that no animation happens.

Any ideas how to do this?
tia
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.
I'm now creating the `ScaleTransform` in my VM, and bind it to the `LayoutTransform` from the `DataTemplate`. Because of this the object stays the same all the time, and doesn't lose its value once the `DataTemplate` is recreated.